# Probability that 3 drawn fruits are different

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Suppose that 1 fruit each is drawn from 3 baskets.
The first basket contains 3 oranges, 2 mangoes and 1 apple, the second one contains 2 oranges, 2 mangoes and 2 apples and ,finally, the third one contains 1 orange, 4 mangoes and 3 apples.
What is the probability that all 3 drawn fruits are different?

Comment: Draw a tree diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The six different combinations are

1. $P(O,M,A) = \frac{3}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{3}{8}$
2. $P(O,A,M) = \frac{3}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{4}{8}$
3. $P(M,O,A) = \frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{3}{8}$
4. $P(M,A,O) = \frac{3}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{1}{8}$
5. $P(A,M,O) = \frac{1}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{1}{8}$
6. $P(A,O,M) = \frac{1}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{4}{8}$

Sum them all you get the probability that all 3 balls are different

Goodluck